# I have ViewpagerActivity.Inside ViewPager Activity there are three fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have ViewpagerActivity.Inside ViewPager Activity there are three fragments.Each view pager fragment has sign up and login button.After clicking on signup or login I am not able to navigate to SignUpPageFragment or LoginPageFragment.I have searched so much but not able to do.

Comment: Please provide a meaningful title, your code, and your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewPager should be placed directly in the FragmentActivity. And you might want to manually set the page you want to display by using the following method:

```
setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll)
```

Also, consider ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener interface to your ViewPager. This will help you to be notified of any changes within your app.